# Need to make Python / Pika code robust - unstable connection and high latency

Tags: python, latency, pika

I am using Python and the Pika library to publish messages to a RabbitMQ server.  The script below will read the last line of a text file every 30 seconds, then publish the last line to the rabbitmq server.

My problem is that the internet connection is very unstable and has a high latency (600ms - 800ms).  The code will run fine for a couple minutes, but then it starts throwing exceptions. The most recent exception is:

```
ERROR:pika.adapters.base_connection:Connection to 64.61.123.233:5672 failed: timeout
WARNING:pika.connection:Could not connect, 2 attempts left

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CF-30 ASCI\Desktop\ascii.py", line 50, in <module>
    dmsPublish(csample)
  File "C:\Users\CF-30 ASCI\Desktop\ascii.py", line 27, in dmsPublish
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params) # Connect to CloudAMQP
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 339, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 410, in _flush_output
    self._impl.ioloop.poll()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\select_connection.py", line 400, in poll
    self.get_next_deadline())
error: (10022, 'An invalid argument was supplied')
```

This exception was thrown after about 5 minutes of running.  I am assuming it is because the internet connection dropped or became unstable.  I would love this script to continue running if there is a failure.  It is OK if I do not receive some of the messages.  I would be happy if 75% made it through given the poor quality of the link.

```
import os
import csv
import time
import pika
import logging
import datetime

logging.basicConfig()

def getLastFile(filename):
    distance = 1024
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        lastline = f.readlines()[-1]
    return lastline

def dmsPublish(message):

    url = os.environ.get('CLOUDAMQP_URL', 'amqp://guest:guest@64.61.123.233/%2f?connection_attempts=3&heartbeat_interval=3600')
    params = pika.URLParameters(url)
    params.socket_timeout = 5
    params.connection_attempts = 3
    params.retry_delay = 3
    print time.ctime() + " [x] Connecting to RabbitMQ server"
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params) # Connect to CloudAMQP
    channel = connection.channel() # start a channel
    channel.queue_declare(queue='LastLine') # Declare a queue    
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='LastLine', body=message)
    print time.ctime() + " [x] Message sent to rabbitMQ"
    connection.close()


loop = 1
while True:
        lastline = getLastFile("teraterm.log")
        sampletime = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + ","
        csample = sampletime + lastline
#        print " [x] Most Recent Sample: " + csample
        try:
            dmsPublish(csample)
        except pika.exceptions.ProbableAccessDeniedError:
            print " [!] Auth error... trying again."
        print time.ctime() + " [x] Sleeping 30 seconds ....."
        time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Did you try alternative amqp libraries? e.g. rabbitpy or amqpstorm to see if you experience the same problem with those?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert related to python, in fact, I am just starting to learn it, but 
why don't you use a try catch inside the dmsPublish method, surrounding the connection code?

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
```

I know it is not a great workaround, but perhaps you can even place a counter to avoid an infinite loop.

This is mere guessing, if you have tried that just disregard.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts!  I just made the changes you suggested, and the program is currently running.  Ill give it an hour or so and see how it holds up....

Comment: Nope, failed again.  Here is exception:                                                                 ERROR:pika.adapters.base_connection:Connection to 64.61.123.233:5672 failed: timeout
WARNING:pika.connection:Could not connect, 2 attempts left
An error occured

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CF-30 ASCI\Desktop\ascii.py", line 53, in <module>
    dmsPublish(csample)
  File "C:\Users\CF-30 ASCI\Desktop\ascii.py", line 31, in dmsPublish
    channel = connection.channel() # start a channel
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'connection' referenced before assignment

Comment: Did you have a time to take a look on the source code of pika?
https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/647

Comment: I did check the server, and I have plenty of resources available.  100%, it is an issue originating at the publisher due to the unstable internet connection.